# Fultter custom OutlinedBorder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In flutter, I can change the shape of a `RaisedButton` to rounded corners by using `shape: RoundedRectangleBorder()` which defived from `OutlinedBorder`

However, I wish to create my own RaisedButton with a pointer shape like this:

[image]

Tried to derive from `OutlinedBorder`, but I can't seems to get it working. Can only get error or Black screen in emulator. May I know what is the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own button by using InkWell widget and then giving a container as its child. Then you can use Custom Clipper to create custom shapes for your container. You can do something like as in code written below:-

```
class MyHome extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
        child:InkWell(
        onTap:(){
        //your function//
        }
        child:ClipPath(
          clipper:ClipButton(),
          child: Container(
            height:100,
            width:250,
            color:Colors.green,
             ),
           ),
         ),
       ),
     );
   }
 }
class ClipButton extends CustomClipper<Path>{
  
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    double h=size.height;
    double w=size.width;
    Path path=new Path();
    path.moveTo(0,0);
    path.lineTo(w*0.75,0);
    path.lineTo(w,h*0.5);
    path.lineTo(w*0.75,h);
    path.lineTo(0,h);
    path.lineTo(0,0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: there is a `RaisedButton.shape` property that should be used for a custom shape, not `ClipPath`

Comment: @pskink but you can only provide rounded shape using shape Property.

Comment: no, you can use any shape you want: just extend `ShapeBorder` class and override `getOuterPath` method

Comment: This is working. I will try to have a look at ``ShapeBorder`` now. It might be easier to follow if only need to override one method. Thx